# can you access the google now api & cards from an API?

Tags: javascript, html, api

I have a little project where I want to display google now cards in a browser (Chrome) window. If you have android phone I pretty much want to replicate the google now desktop gadget but on a browser using javascript/html etc

Is the google now api available for this sort of stuff? I cant see it.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken - the idea is to put your content into Google Now. Your application would create cards to be displayed within Google Now. I'm not sure that it will be possible to "embed" actual Google Now cards somewhere else.

Comment: Hi there, yes the idea is to embed google now cards in a custom app.. I pretty much want to recreate the google now "widget" available on android mobile phones....